# Software to model electromagnetic field

Tags: modeling

Is there any software for to modeling alternating electromagnetic field in xyz-coordinates?

I need to calculate (to see) some effects for a П-shaped conductor in that field.

I know Matlab, but maybe there is something else?

Comment: There are many. Some well-known names include Ansys, CST, Momentum.

Comment: meep https://meep.readthedocs.io/en/latest/